# To solve a geometric proof, do we need an image of the shape described in a problem to solve it?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

To solve a geometric proof, for example, a two-column proof, do you need an image of the shape being described in the problem? If you are only told the "givens" of the problem and what you are trying to prove, would you be able to solve it? Given the proper algorithms, could something like a computer program solve a geometric proof without an image of the shape described in the problem?

For an extremely basic example, say you have a quadrilateral named ABCD, and you have to prove it is a parallelogram. You are given the fact that the sides AB||CD, and the side AB is congruent to the side CD. Would a computer program (or would we) need an image to solve this? And if yes, for more complex problems would we also not need an image?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve a geometric problem with only a description and not an image.

E.G.:

Nontrivial Problem:

If ABC is a right triangle with right angle at C, and if BD is any line cutting AC at point D, prove that $BD^{2}+AC^{2}=AB^{2}+DC^{2}$.

Solution:

DBC is also a right triangle with a right angle at C so from the Pythagorean Theorem:

$$DB^{2}=CD^{2}+CB^{2}$$

$$AB^{2}=CA^{2}+CB^{2}$$

So,

$$DB^{2}+CA^{2}=(CD^{2}+CB^{2})+(AB^{2}−CB^{2})=CD^{2}+AB^{2}$$

P.S.: Images can help you understand though. Nothing wrong with them.

Side Note: Also how would we do geometry that can't be immersed in 3d if we relied on pictures all the time.